# How do I create a converter so that JsonConvert.DeserializeObject will convert List<string> properties to just string properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, type-conversion

I have the following class...

```
public class ResultDTO
{
    public string MSAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string MSCaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public string StatCode { get; set; }
}
```

Unsurprisingly, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is unable to convert the following JSON into that object....

```
    {
      "StatusMessage": [
        "Record processed successfully"
      ],
      "StatCode": [
        "200"
      ],
      "MSCaseNumber": [
        "500"
      ],
      "MSAccountNumber": [
        "001"
      ]
    }
```

I have asked the API creator if he can change the API so that the returned JSON has string properties instead of `List<string>` properties.  But in case he is unable to accommodate that, how do I implement and use a `JsonConverter` so that `JsonConvert` will successfully convert that JSON into my target class. Assume that all of the List properties in the JSON will have at least one item (is never null or empty) and we want to take the first item.

I know this can be done but I have no idea how.

Comment: Not sure i get why the API would need to change, as that would require other consumers of it to change. Is ResultDTO a class that you can modify? If so, i'd change the properties to Lists, and then if you have code that wants the data as a String, implement another method that does that (so you'd have StatusMessage and StatusMessageString or something).

Comment: @JonE that is a good question and I thought it might come up.  It is a Salesforce API that as been created just for us.  In that respect it is not at all a public API and we are the only consumers.  Good question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a converter that should work for you:

```
class StringArrayToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String) return (string)reader.Value;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
            string value = (string)array.Children<JValue>().FirstOrDefault();
            return value;
        }
        throw new JsonException("Unexpected token type: " + reader.TokenType);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultDTO>(json, new StringArrayToStringConverter());
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kLbn2P

Comment: Brian, it did work.  Perfect.  In fact, I changed your fiddle because the response was actually a LIST of those list properties....but it still worked.  So I guess the converter only "kicks in" when it encounters types that are defined in the jsonconverter.  Right?  Anyway thanks for the great answer.

Comment: If you mean the response had a list of objects representing your DTO, then yes, the converter will still work because it responds to any properties defined as string in any DTO, whether the DTO is in a list or not. If you mean that any of the individual properties in the JSON could be an array of arrays of strings, then in that case the converter would "work" only to the extent that it would not throw an exception, but you would get null values in your DTO because it is only expecting single-depth arrays for each string. It is easy to modify the converter to handle that case too, though.